# How to add explicit WHERE clause in Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, db2, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka connect to source data from DB2 to kafka topic and i am configuring sql query to read the data from DB2 , below is query

```
SELECT SEQ_I AS error_id, TRIM(SEND_I) AS sca , to_char(CREATE_TS,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS create_timestamp, CREATE_TS, TRIM(ERR_MSG) AS error_message , CASE substr(ERR_MSG,1,locate('-',ERR_MSG)-1) WHEN 'WARNING' THEN 'W' WHEN 'SUSPENDED' THEN 'F' END ERROR_TYPE FROM INTCHG_ERROR_DIR WHERE TRAN_I ='503' AND PRCS_N = 'GLOBAL'
```

am using setting `"timestamp.column.name": "CREATE_TS"` here problem is in the query their is already `WHERE` clause , and kafka connect tried to add another where clause with timestamp column and it is creating issue and one more issue is if i remove where clause from sql clause like below

```
SELECT SEQ_I AS error_id, TRIM(SEND_I) AS sca , to_char(CREATE_TS,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS create_timestamp, CREATE_TS, TRIM(ERR_MSG) AS error_message , CASE substr(ERR_MSG,1,locate('-',ERR_MSG)-1) WHEN 'WARNING' THEN 'W' WHEN 'SUSPENDED' THEN 'F' END ERROR_TYPE FROM INTCHG_ERROR_DIR
```

then am getting error with substr , like below

```
SQL Error [22011]: THE SECOND OR THIRD ARGUMENT OF THE SUBSTR OR SUBSTRING FUNCTION IS OUT OF RANGE. SQLCODE=-138, SQLSTATE=22011, DRIVER=4.19.26
```

can anyone suggest on both is this issues , am stuck at this point .

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you are trying to use both `"mode": "timestamp"` and `query`. `TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier` appends a `WHERE` clause to the query that conflicts with existing `WHERE` clauses in the `query`.

[JDBC source connector docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/source-connector/source_config_options.html) is clear on this:

> `query`
>
> If specified, the query to perform to select new or updated rows. Use
> this setting if you want to join tables, select subsets of columns in
> a table, or filter data. If used, this connector will only copy data
> using this query -- whole-table copying will be disabled. Different
> query modes may still be used for incremental updates, but in order to
> properly construct the incremental query, it must be possible to
> append a WHERE clause to this query (i.e. no WHERE clauses may be
> used). **If you use a WHERE clause, it must handle incremental queries
> itself**.

---

As a workaround, you can modify your query to (depending on what SQL flavour are you using)

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...)
```

or

```
WITH a AS
   SELECT * FROM b
    WHERE ...
SELECT * FROM a
```

For example, in your case the query should be

```
"query":"SELECT * FROM (SELECT SEQ_I AS error_id, TRIM(SEND_I) AS sca , to_char(CREATE_TS,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3') AS create_timestamp, CREATE_TS, TRIM(ERR_MSG) AS error_message , CASE substr(ERR_MSG,1,locate('-',ERR_MSG)-1) WHEN 'WARNING' THEN 'W' WHEN 'SUSPENDED' THEN 'F' END ERROR_TYPE FROM INTCHG_ERROR_DIR WHERE TRAN_I ='503' AND PRCS_N = 'GLOBAL') o"
```