# MySql query fails in Kafka-connect

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka connect (confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0) and have MySQL connector installed in it. Basically the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.4.0

RUN echo "===> Installing MySQL connector" \
    && curl -k -SL "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.tar.gz" | tar -xzf - -C /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar
```

I created a connector with the following configurations:

```sh
curl -X POST http://localhost:8083/connectors -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
        "name": "test-connector",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://10.xx.yy.z:3306/demo_db?user=user&password=pass",
                "topic.prefix": "test-connector-",
                "mode":"incrementing",
                "query":"$QUERY",
                "incrementing.column.name": "eventId",
                "validate.non.null": false
                }
        }'
```

I tried replacing the "$QUERY" mentioned above with the following query (pasting a formatted version for better readability):

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( 
    select DISTINCT t1.id,
            t1.name,
            t1.email,
            t1.department,
            t1.modified
        from
            test as t1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN test as t2 ON t1.id > -1
        WHERE
            t1.id > -1) something
```

The above connector gets created and works as expected. However, the below query fails. and

```sql
SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT
            HSC.id eventId,
            HSC.actions,
            HSC.cause,
            HSC.metaData,
            CRED.uid uidCard,
            CRED.is_primary isPrimary,
            CRED.type cardType,
            PR.keys_ prin,
            HOUSE.uid orgUid,
            CHILD.uid childUid,
            USER.first_name fName,
            USER.last_name lName,
            CHILD.biz_phone bizPh,
            CHILD.cell_phone cellPh,
            AOF.state aof_state,
            RECORD.uid replacedCardUid
        FROM
            house_of_cards as HSC
            INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id
            INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id
            INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id
            INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id
            INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id
            LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id
            LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id
            LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id
        WHERE
        HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards
```

*EDIT: 1. Posting full error log*  (with modified sensitive data of course)

```
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,463] INFO AbstractConfig values:                                                                                                                                                                           
        batch.max.rows = 100                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        catalog.pattern = null                                                                                                                                                                                                  
        connection.attempts = 3                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        connection.backoff.ms = 10000                                                                                                                                                                                           
        connection.password = null                                                                                                                                                                                              
        connection.url = jdbc:mysql://10.xx.yy.z:3306/demo_db?user=user&password=pass                                                                                        
        connection.user = null
        db.timezone = UTC
        dialect.name =
        incrementing.column.name = eventId
        mode = incrementing
        numeric.mapping = null
        numeric.precision.mapping = false
        poll.interval.ms = 5000
        query = SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards
        quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
        schema.pattern = null
        table.blacklist = []
        table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
        table.types = [TABLE]
        table.whitelist = []
        timestamp.column.name = []
        timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
        topic.prefix = card-view-test
        validate.non.null = false
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,595] INFO AbstractConfig values:
 (org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,601] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Connector card-view-test config updated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,602] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Rebalance started (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.WorkerCoordinator)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,602] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,609] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Successfully joined group with generation 295 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,609] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Joined group at generation 295 with protocol version 2 and got assignment: Assignment{error=0, leader='connect-1-d82cc98e-5
619-4972-ad78-3b0a53c3b5bb', leaderUrl='http://10.xx.yy.36:8083/', offset=433, connectorIds=[card-view-test], taskIds=[card-view-test-0], revokedConnectorIds=[], revokedTaskIds=[], delay=0} with rebalance delay: 0 (org.apache
.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,609] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Starting connectors and tasks using config offset 433 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,609] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Starting connector card-view-test (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,609] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Starting task card-view-test-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO Creating task card-view-test-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO ConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart                                                                                                                                                                                          
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector                                                                                                                                                         
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO Creating connector card-view-test of type io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO ConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO TaskConfig values:
        task.class = class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO Instantiated task card-view-test-0 with version 5.4.0 of type io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,610] INFO Instantiated connector card-view-test with version 5.4.0 of type class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,611] INFO Starting JDBC Source Connector (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,611] INFO JdbcSourceConnectorConfig values:
        batch.max.rows = 100
        catalog.pattern = null
        connection.attempts = 3
        connection.backoff.ms = 10000
        connection.password = null
        connection.url = jdbc:mysql://10.xx.yy.z:3306/demo_db?user=user&password=pass
        connection.user = null
        db.timezone = UTC
        dialect.name =
        incrementing.column.name = eventId
        mode = incrementing
        numeric.mapping = null
        numeric.precision.mapping = false
        poll.interval.ms = 5000
        query = SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards
        quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS                                                                                                                                                                                          
        schema.pattern = null                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        table.blacklist = []                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        table.poll.interval.ms = 60000                                                                                                                                                                                          
        table.types = [TABLE]                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        table.whitelist = []                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        tables = []                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        timestamp.column.name = []                                                                                                                                                                                              
        timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0                                                                                                                                                                                         
        topic.prefix = card-view-test-25                                                                                                                                                                                        
        validate.non.null = false                                                                                                                                                                                               
 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTaskConfig)                                                                                                                                                                        
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,621] INFO Using JDBC dialect MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)                                                                                                                       
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,681] INFO Started JDBC source task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)                                                                                                                       
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,681] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=card-view-test-0} Source task finished initialization and start (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)                                                          
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,681] INFO Attempting to open connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider)                                                                                              
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,723] INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-card-view-test-0] Cluster ID: XXOJHDDIEHID-YYGDIEDi82eeh (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)                                                                   
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,732] INFO Starting thread to monitor tables. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread)                                                                                                         
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,735] INFO Finished creating connector card-view-test (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)                                                                                                             
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,736] INFO SourceConnectorConfig values:                                                                                                                                                                    
        config.action.reload = restart                                                                                                                                                                                          
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector                                                                                                                                                         
        errors.log.enable = false                                                                                                                                                                                               
        errors.log.include.messages = false                                                                                                                                                                                     
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000                                                                                                                                                                                       
        errors.retry.timeout = 0                                                                                                                                                                                                
        errors.tolerance = none                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SourceConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,737] INFO EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = card-view-test
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig)
[2020-02-16 20:31:46,949] INFO Begin using SQL query: SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, 
 CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, 
 USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid 
 FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id 
 INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id 
 LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id 
 LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards events WHERE `eventId` > ? ORDER BY `eventId` ASC (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier)

[2020-02-16 20:31:46,954] ERROR Failed to run query for table TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier{table=null, query='SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, 
 CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, 
 USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid 
 FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id 
 INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id 
 LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id 
 LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = "cardActionKamen" )', topicPrefix='card-view-test-25', incrementingColumn='eventId', timestampColumns=[]
}: {} (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'demo_db.HSC' doesn't exist
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor48.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1369)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Field.getCollation(Field.java:448)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetMetaData.isCaseSensitive(ResultSetMetaData.java:552)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.describeColumn(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:713)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.dialect.GenericDatabaseDialect.describeColumns(GenericDatabaseDialect.java:655)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.SchemaMapping.create(SchemaMapping.java:63)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TableQuerier.java:94)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.maybeStartQuery(TimestampIncrementingTableQuerier.java:61)
        at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask.poll(JdbcSourceTask.java:315)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:265)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:232)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,109] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Tasks [card-view-test-0] configs updated (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,611] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Finished starting connectors and tasks (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,613] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=alpha-core-kafka-connect-wrapper] Handling task config update by restarting tasks [card-view-test-0] (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.Distribute
dHerder)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,613] INFO Stopping task card-view-test-0 (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,614] INFO Stopping JDBC source task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,656] INFO Closing resources for JDBC source task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceTask)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,656] INFO Closing connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,657] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=card-view-test-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,657] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=card-view-test-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask)
[2020-02-16 20:31:47,657] INFO [Producer clientId=connector-producer-card-view-test-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
```

***EDIT 2. Adding connetor config***

```
{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "eventId",
    "topic.prefix": "test-connector",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards",
    "name": "test-connector-",
    "connection.url": "dbc:mysql://10.xx.yy.z:3306/demo_db?user=user&password=pass"
}
```

Both the queries have WHERE clause, use aliases, have JOINS, etc. Their functionalities seem identical to me, how come one works and the other doesn't? Is there any limit on the length of the query? Is this related to the version of Mysql (I am using 5.7 provided by GCP) or the [connector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) version (I have downloaded 5.1.39 as you can see in the above Dockerfile)?

I have also tried creating a MySQL view of both the subqueries (the sub-SELECT queries) mentioned in the above queries and that works okay for both the queries. Any idea of what might be the issue here?

Comment: *However, the below query fails* Where is the error message (full!)? And what is the reason to wrap the query into excess `SELECT *`?

Comment: Because there is a WHERE clause which would fail without the external SELECT. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/112), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629360/how-to-add-explicit-where-clause-in-kafka-connect-jdbc-source-connector) and [this](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/566)

Comment: *there is a WHERE clause which would fail without the external SELECT.* ?? this is kafka connector feature - none WHERE clause in the outer query??? JDBC connector easily processes the queries without `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ...) alias` wrapping.

Comment: Please provide error log

Comment: So you tried creating a VIEW for that query then having connect read that? What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Akina Yes, please see the links I have provided it will be helpful to understand the wrapping. If you could provide an alternate query as an answer without it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander I have added the error log. Please have a look

Comment: @cricket_007 creating a VIEW is an alternative that is working. But I would like to avoid the extra step to create a new VIEW every time I want to create a connector with complicated queries like this. Also, would like to understand why it doesn't work without the view?

Comment: @AmitYadav, ok, please show output of  `curl -X GET http://localhost:8083/connectors/test-connecot/config`. Looks like you made a typo in the connector config (`evenId` instead of `eventId` for `incrementing.column.name`)

Comment: Read the error log closely... `Unknown column 'evenId' in 'where clause'`

Comment: By the way, it's sometimes better to use KSQL to join topics rather than SQL to join tables, depending on how raw you want the data. For example, you can use Debezium to read your DB writes rather than use JDBC polling

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander cricket_007 my BAD!!!!! While doing it for the question I made the mistake. I have updated the error log after fixing the typo and have also added the config.

Comment: @AmitYadav Is there a problem running the query in the DB console?

Comment: No. The query runs fine in MySql console. Works fine! I get 162 records.

Comment: @AmitYadav Can you add stacktace lines to show jdbc connector exception? Did you connect to MySql exactly like in your connector config (`dbc:mysql://10.xx.yy.z:3306/demo_db?user=user&password=pass`)?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander stacktrace as in? And yes, I'm exactly connecting like that. I can see other queries running okay. But this one.

Comment: @AmitYadav, yes, full stacktrace. You could use such tool like https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander cricket_007 I have updated the question once more to include full error logs. (Of course, some of the data has been modified for security reasons). Also ignore if the name of the connector or prefix topic is different. Because I tried creating the connector again to post the error on SO with random names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case.

1. Create tables in `demo_db`:

```
mysql> show tables;
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_demo_db |
+-------------------+
| address           |
| child             |
| house             |
| house_of_cards    |
| play_card         |
| prin              |
| user              |
+-------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

2. Connector launch:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://myhost:10900/connectors/test-connector/config' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "eventId",
    "topic.prefix": "test-connector",
    "validate.non.null": "false",
    "query": "SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = '\''cardActionKamen'\'' ) playcards",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/demo_db?user=isk&password=123"
}'
```

3. Connector logs:

```
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,589] INFO [test-connector|worker] Creating connector test-connector of type io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:251)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,592] INFO [test-connector|worker] Instantiated connector test-connector with version 5.3.1 of type class io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:254)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,592] INFO [test-connector|worker] Starting JDBC Source Connector (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector:69)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,592] INFO [test-connector|worker] JdbcSourceConnectorConfig values: 
        batch.max.rows = 100
        catalog.pattern = null
        connection.attempts = 3
        connection.backoff.ms = 10000
        connection.password = null
        connection.url = jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/demo_db?user=isk&password=123
        connection.user = null
        db.timezone = UTC
        dialect.name = 
        incrementing.column.name = eventId
        mode = incrementing
        numeric.mapping = null
        numeric.precision.mapping = false
        poll.interval.ms = 5000
        query = SELECT * FROM( SELECT HSC.id eventId, HSC.actions, HSC.cause, HSC.metaData, CRED.uid uidCard, CRED.is_primary isPrimary, CRED.type cardType, PR.keys_ prin, HOUSE.uid orgUid, CHILD.uid childUid, USER.first_name fName, USER.last_name lName, CHILD.biz_phone bizPh, CHILD.cell_phone cellPh, AOF.state aof_state, RECORD.uid replacedCardUid FROM house_of_cards as HSC INNER JOIN play_card as CRED ON HSC.debit_card_id = CRED.id INNER JOIN prin PR ON CRED.prin_id = PR.id INNER JOIN child CHILD ON CRED.employee_id = CHILD.id INNER JOIN user USER ON USER.id = CHILD.user_id INNER JOIN house HOUSE ON CHILD.house_id = HOUSE.id LEFT JOIN address SHPADDR ON CRED.shipping_address = SHPADDR.id LEFT JOIN address AOF ON CRED.address_on_file = AOF.id LEFT JOIN play_card RECORD ON CRED.replaced_card_id = RECORD.id WHERE HSC.type = 'cardActionKamen' ) playcards
        quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
        schema.pattern = null
        table.blacklist = []
        table.poll.interval.ms = 60000
        table.types = [TABLE]
        table.whitelist = []
        timestamp.column.name = []
        timestamp.delay.interval.ms = 0
        topic.prefix = test-connector
        validate.non.null = false
 (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.JdbcSourceConnectorConfig:347)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,594] INFO [test-connector|worker] Attempting to open connection #1 to MySql (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.util.CachedConnectionProvider:87)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,640] INFO [test-connector|worker] Starting thread to monitor tables. (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.source.TableMonitorThread:73)
[2020-02-17 02:17:17,641] INFO [test-connector|worker] Finished creating connector test-connector (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker:273)
```

So there is *no error* and everything works fine.

---

Used versions:

1. *Kafka Connect*:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:10900 | jq '.version'

"2.4.0"
```

2. *Jdbc Source Connector*:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:10900/connector-plugins | jq -c '.[] | select( .class == "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector") | .version'

"5.3.1"
```

3. *MySql jdbc driver*:

```
8.0.19
```

Comment: So the problem was ***mysql-connector-java-5.1.39*** . I used the JDBC driver 8.0.19 and all the queries work fine. This should be a part of some documentation or some warning rather than being a recommendation :|

Comment: @AmitYadav, I initially did not pay attention to your version, so I used the latest driver.
I hope I helped you! All the best!

Comment: Directly or indirectly your answer helped to solve the problem here! Thank you, I will be able to award the bounty in the next 11 hours and I will do that to this answer. Cheers mate!

Comment: Thanks @IskuskovAlexander for your answer. I am also getting the same issue like above so really appreciate if you give your feedback on it:

I am getting this error whenever I am trying to apply any filter on the query like where:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `ID` > -1 ORDER BY `ID` ASC' at line 1

Query: select * from (select ID, applid from credit_lines where applid in ('CAD')) creditlines;

Also check the confluent JDBC connection version: 10.6.3

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander json:

{
  "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
  "mode": "incrementing",
  "incrementing.column.name": "cust_line_nbr",
  "topic.prefix": "credit.creditlines.creditline-detials.in",
  "validate.non.null": "false",
  "query": "select * from (select ID, applid,cust_line_nbr from credit_lines where applid in ('CAD')) creditlines;",
  "name": "creditLine-details-1",
  "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/silicon?user=root&password=root"
}